# I am trying to draw a DNA sequence with a point mutaion

Tags: graphics

I am trying to draw the following:

```
    met thr glu tyr lys leu val val val gly ala gly gly 
ORF ATG ACG GAA TAT AAG CTG GTG GTG GTG GGC GCC GGC GGT
    TAC TGC CTT ATA TTC GAC CAC CAC CAC CCG CGG CCG CCA
                                                 *
                                                val
    ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... GTC ...
    ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... CAG ...
                                                 *
```

where the G-C and T-A are highlighted in blue and red respectively (I don't want to include the stars). I want to show a point mutation in a DNA sequence that caused a major structural change in an oncogene. I have started using latex to draw regular graphs, which are quite beautiful. However, I don't know how to draw DNA sequences. I would greatly appreciate if someone could please refer me to a tutorial or similar question. I want this in a standalone.

Thank you!

Comment: Search this site for DNA.  There are 80 hits and many discuss graphic displays of DNA.  Recommend you review them, select one of the example LaTeX code provided,  then modify it for your particular situation.  If you then have a specific problem create a MWE to illustrate what you specifically need.